# php- foreach iteration failed for array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays like given below

```
<?php
    $series = array 
    ( 
        0 => "Series A", 
        1 => "Series B", 
        2 => "Series C", 
        3 => "Series D", 
        4 => "Series E", 
        5 => "Series F" 
    );

    $episodes = array 
    ( 
        0 => array ( 0 => "a0" ), 
        1 => array ( 0 => "b0", 1 => "b1" ), 
        2 => array ( 0 => "c0", 1 => "c1" ), 
        3 => array ( 0 => "d0" ),
        4 => array ( 0 => "e0" ),
        5 => array ( 0 => "f0" ) 
    ); 
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to link these two arrays so the output will look like this

**Desired Output**

```
Series A- a0
Series B- b0, b1
Series C- c0, c1
Series D- d0
Series E- e0
Series F- f0
```

To achieve this, I iterated the arrays like this but I'm not getting the desired output.

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($series); $i++)
        {
            foreach($episodes as $row => $innerArray){
                foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
                    $value = $value.', ';
                }
                echo "<li>".$series[$i]."-     ".$value."</li>";
            }

        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: How you sure about binding element in arrays with keys ? are length always same for both array ?

Comment: Yes, length will be same for both arrays @Rishi Raut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple starting code:

```
foreach ($series as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' - ' . implode(', ', $episodes[$key]) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/XKZYY).

Answer (score 1):

First you can combine your array and then you can iterate on single array instead of two arrays

```
$new = array_combine($series,$episodes);
foreach($new as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . ' - ' . implode(', ',$value).'<br>';
}
```

output :

```
Series A - a0
Series B - b0, b1
Series C - c0, c1
Series D - d0
Series E - e0
Series F - f0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($series as $sKey => $sValue) {
    print sprintf('%s- %s%s', $sValue, implode(', ', $episodes[$sKey]), PHP_EOL);
}
```

note that you don't really want to use `sizeof()`, because it's an alias for `count()` and you should not really use it inside a loop.